# how can i apply sessionstorage on the traget data attribute

Tags: javascript, dom, session-storage

```js
if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("input")) {
  document
  .querySelectorAll('input')
  .forEach( (a) => { 
     document.querySelectorAll(`[data-in]`).value = window.sessionStorage.getItem("input")
   })
}
document.querySelectorAll('input').foreach((input)=> {  
  input.addEventListener('input', ()=> {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("input", input.value )
   })
})
```

each input field has data attribute called `data-in`

Comment: Add more details to your question to make it understandable.

Comment: you would be wrong to use an input event for each element. Just the one in the form is sufficient for this.